# AEM/CQ Multiple Image Component

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm trying to create a component with two images and some information, i have created the dialog, managed to create the nodes and upload the image. Everything works fine but i can't find a way to get the image's path or render it.

This is what i have so far:

```
<%@ page import="com.day.text.Text,
               com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Image,
               com.day.cq.commons.Doctype" %>
<%@include file="/apps/platform/aem-core/global/global.jsp"%>

<%
    Image image = new Image(resource, "image1");

    out.println(image);

    image.draw(out);
%>

<h2><%=image.getSrc()%></h2>
```

This gives me: /content/region-growth/brazil/brazil-poc/pt-br/home/jcr:content/leadmachine-new/image1/file.jpg/1456255696906.jpg and if i go to this folder there is a node called image1 > file. The image is there, if i try to download it using crxde i can open it so i believe my problem is with the path.

This is the dialog XML:

```
<dialog jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
        title="Lead Machine"
        xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:TabPanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <generalTab jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                        title="Geral">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <campanhaID jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                allowBlank="false"
                                fieldLabel="Campanha ID"
                                name="./jcr:campanhaid"
                                xtype="textfield" />
                    <titulo jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            allowBlank="false"
                            fieldLabel="Título"
                            name="./jcr:titulo"
                            xtype="textfield" />
                    <corFundo jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                              allowBlank="false"
                              fieldLabel="Cor de Fundo"
                              name="./jcr:corfundo"
                              xtype="colormenu" />
                    <corBotao jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                              allowBlank="false"
                              fieldLabel="Cor do Botão"
                              name="./jcr:corbotao"
                              xtype="colormenu" />
                    <txtBotao jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                              allowBlank="false"
                              fieldLabel="Texto do Botão"
                              ame="./jcr:txtBotao"
                              xtype="textfield" />
                    <texto jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                           allowBlank="true"
                           fieldLabel="Texto"
                           name="./jcr:texto"
                           xtype="richtext" />
                    <observacao jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                allowBlank="true"
                                fieldLabel="Observação"
                                name="./jcr:observacao"
                                xtype="richtext" />
                    <layoutForm jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                fieldDescription="LM com formato simples"
                                fieldLabel="Layout Form"
                                inputValue="true"
                                name="./layoutForm"
                                type="checkbox"
                                xtype="selection" />
                    <agendamento jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                 fieldDescription="LM com agendamento"
                                 fieldLabel="Agendamento"
                                 inputValue="true"
                                 name="./agendamento"
                                 type="checkbox"
                                 xtype="selection" />
                    <ativo jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                           fieldLabel="Ativo"
                           inputValue="true"
                           name="./ativo"
                           type="checkbox"
                           xtype="selection" />
                </items>
            </generalTab>
            <tab1 jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel" title="Image Properties">
                <image1ResType jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" ignoreData="{Boolean}true" name="./image1/sling:resourceType" value="foundation/components/image" xtype="hidden"/>
                <image2ResType jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" ignoreData="{Boolean}true" name="./image2/sling:resourceType" value="foundation/components/image" xtype="hidden"/>
            </tab1>
            <tab2 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  cropParameter="./imageCrop"
                  fileNameParameter="./fileName"
                  fileReferenceParameter="./fileReference"
                  mapParameter="./imageMap"
                  name="./file"
                  requestSuffix="/img.jpg"
                  rotateParameter="./imageRotate"
                  title="Image 1"
                  xtype="html5smartimage" />
            <tab3 jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                  cropParameter="./mdImageCrop"
                  fileNameParameter="./mdFileName"
                  fileReferenceParameter="./mdFileReference"
                  mapParameter="./mdImageMap"
                  name="./mdFile"
                  requestSuffix="/mdImage.img.jpg"
                  rotateParameter="./mdImageRotate"
                  title="Image 2"
                  xtype="html5smartimage" />
        </items>
    </items>
</dialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Node childNode = currentNode.getNode("file");
if (childNode != null) {
    if (childNode.hasProperty("fileReferenceParameter")) {
        return childNode.getProperty("fileReferenceParameter").getString();
    }
}
```

And why do you use hidden `imageResType` in `tab1`?

Also you may use the following using image object:

```
<% 
     Image image = new Image(resource, "file"); 
%>    

<img src='<%=image.getSrc()'/>
```

Comment: Well, i copied part of this dialog from another one that had what i wanted, two image upload. Right now i have another problem as well, first time i upload the image to the component it shows the image, when i reload the page and edit the component on visual the image dissapears, what could it be ?

Comment: @Terkhos add please errors log from browser's console, or try to debub by yourself

Comment: Your code didn't work, what should i get on the return ? I can't debug, my user doesn't have access to this i believe. Your code fails on childNode.getProperty("fileReferenceParameter")

Comment: @Terkhos provide concreate reason please. Is it exception or smth else?

Comment: @Terkhos fileReferenceParameter is path to your's image in dam

Comment: if i "dump" the var using out.println i get: `Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/content/region-growth/brazil/brazil-poc/pt-br/home/jcr:content/leadmachine-new/image1: { jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured, jcr:lastModifiedBy = leandro_rocha, jcr:lastModified = 2016-02-23T19:53:12.029Z, imageRotate = 0, file = { ... }}}]`. If i try to get the fileReferenceParameter i get a null response and if i get the file i get a exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104425/discussion-between-terkhos-and-cylinder-y).